# What OpenGL libraries do I use with Windows API?

Tags: winapi, opengl

I have run in to a problem when programming with windows api. I want to use OpenGL's shader capabilities in my project. I included and linked GLFW with my project but got this error.

```
warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

Should i be using GLWF with Windows API or should I be using something else completely ?

Comment: I'm currently very happy with glew and creating my windows and opengl contexts in an OS-dependent manner - it's portable as far as you port your window/context creation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is caused by the GLFW binary you're trying to link using a different CRT than what the linker wants to link with your program. In particular the brew of GLFW you have seems to have been build with either a VC++ compiler of Visual Studio 6 or older *or* the MinGW compilers.

Since a modern MSVC++ compiler will refuse to link against system MSVCRT without jumping some serious hoops (od you'd have to use the Windows DDK compiler for that), the two options open to you are:

- get a DLL build of GLFW into which the CRT has been linked statically
- build a DLL version of GLFW with the very compiler you use right now
- build a static linked library variant of GLFW and link it statically to your program (static library build usually are not tied to a particular CRT).

Answer (score -4):

Firstly, why would you want to be using Windows API at all? If you're using OpenGL then a multi-platform API such as GLFW would be wise since it handles the Windows API stuff for you. If you want to use Windows API then that's your choice, the same with GLFW. But remember not to mix the two together, otherwise there will be a conflict. In my opinion, if you use GLFW your code will be portable to other operating systems.

Comment: Somebody may want to write a GUI program that uses OpenGL for displaying content and the Windows API for implementing controls like buttons, checkboxes, menus, etc. that are outside the content area. GLFW doesn't provide that.

Comment: Technically, you can create buttons, checkboxes and menus albeit requires more programming than is required. Wherein, you might as well use Qt since it goes well with OpenGL. Windows API and OpenGL is like putting a lion and a mouse in the same room harmoniously.

Comment: When i use glew do i also have to use something like glut as well ?

Comment: @Poriferous: OP's problem has nothing to do with the direct use of Windows API. It's a linking problem, specifically a library version mismatch, caused by that the GLFW binary OP has is linked against a different CRT than the linker wants to use for his own program.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, and doesn't provide a solution. The advice given will not solve the issue at hand: a linking problem, as pointed out by @datenwolf already.

Comment: I'm glad to be of service. Come again!